# Amazon Amplify GraphQL call with API_KEY

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have created a site where an user can login and do things with a GraphQL table. That works fine. But now there is a need to have a public read access to that table.

schema.grapql:

```
type Garden @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public, operations: [read]}] {
    id: ID!
    name: String
}
```

I am aware that allow: public means only Authorized users can access this. So public is not *true* public.

With the following call (Javascript):

```
await API.graphql({ 
    query: listGardens,
    authMode: 'API_KEY',
    authToken: 'token_from_amazon_aplify_backend'
})
```

But this call only returns **_deleted** items. What am I missing here?

- GraphQL is installed and working.
- Auth is installed and working with login with users.

Comment: I have the same problem, any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your "listGardens" query but if you filter out the _deleted it should do the trick, like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  listGardens(filter:{_deleted:{eq:null}}) {
    items {
      id
      _deleted
    }
  }
}
```